# Eclipse: How to change Android Project name while keeping its source code directory name unchanged?

Tags: android, eclipse

As a personal preference, I like to have my Android Application Project name in the UpperCamelCase format such as "MyAndroidApp" while its source code directory name in the lower-case format such as "/home/user/projects/myandroidapp".

This does not appear to be possible when creating a brand-new project named "MyNewAndroidApp", because Eclipse will save the source code under "/home/user/projects/MyNewAndroidApp" which is not what I wanted. Now if I use -> Project -> Refactor -> Rename, and replace "MyNewAndroidApp" with "mynewandroidapp", the new source code directory name will be good (i.e., in all lower cases), but the new project name will not be (i.e., also in all lower cases).

Neither does this appear to be possible with an existing project named "myoldandroidapp" whose source code directory name is "/home/user/projects/myoldandroidapp". I just can't change the project name to "MyOldAndroidApp" while keeping its source code directory name unchanged. I have also tried to modify file ".project" but still can't achieve my goal.

After some further investigation, I have noticed that:

- the project name is tied to -> Properties -> Resource -> Path
- the source code directory name is tied to -> Properties -> Resource -> Location

However, these project properties do not appear to be modifiable.

If it is not possible to change the project name while keeping the source code directory name unchanged inside Eclipse IDE, is it possible to achieve the goal outside of Eclipse IDE?

Comment: The goal is to separate the project name from the source code directory name: Use UpperCamelCase format for the project name and lower-case format for the source code directory name.

Comment: By contrast, Android Studio (Release 1.3.1) allows decoupling the "Application name" from the "Project location". For example, Application named "MyNewAndroidApp" can be created with its project location specified as "/home/user/as_projects/mynewandroidapp". It would be great if Eclipse could also have this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is impossible because the project name is also the name of the source code folder in workspace (as default) or where you keep the source code. Any changes using "Refactor" in Eclipse also affect to folder name.

As naming convention, I suggest you should name your project name as UpperCameCase.

Comment: I agree with you that Eclipse is not very flexible in decoupling project name from its source code folder name. Android Studio appears doing a better job.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, I have found a way to achieve the goal when creating a brand-new Android project "MyNewAndroidApp":

- Step 1: Create the source code directory first.

For example, type:

```
mkdir -p /home/user/projects/android/mynewandroidapp
```

Make sure that there is **an extra directory level "android"** between "projects" and "mynewandroidapp".

- Step 2: Open Eclipse. Create project "MyNewAndroidApp" in the usual way, until arriving at page "Configure Project". Uncheck "Create Project in Workspace". In "Location", change the default substring "MyNewAndroidApp" to "android/mynewandroidapp". Finish the project creation.

Now the project name is "MyNewAndroidApp" while the source code directory name is "/home/user/projects/android/mynewandroidapp". The goal has been achieved.

Following are some limitations of this solution:

- An extra directory level ("android") is needed. This may or may not be desirable.
- For an existing Android project, achieving this goal also implies to add the extra directory level ("android") between the workspace and the source code sub-directory. Again, this may or may not be desirable.